# Is it possible to subscribe to a local variable in an Angular component?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm using Angular 8, and I'm newbie.

I need to listen to a variabel. When it's have 0 value, the view show loader animation (loader css). And when it is already populated, it show the data.

I'm doing this way

```
this.data.subscribe(...)
```

and it shows error.

Is that any possible way to do this things ?

Comment: what is `this.data` in this case? Just a number? Then no, this won't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to be notified when a property value changes is to implement the property as a getter/setter. You can then do extra processing in the setter:

```
private _data: number;

public get data(): number {
  return this._data;
}

public set data(value: number) {
  this._data = value;
  // Do something here after changing the value
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on when you are subscribing it. 
Try to subscribe it in `ngAfterViewInit()` method:

```
ngAfterViewInit()
{
    this.data.subscribe(...)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alif, you can create a getter and setter for a variable, and on this setter you publish the changes, like this:

```
private _data: any;
private _data$ = new BehaviorSubject(this._data);
set data(value) {
  this._data = value;
  this._data$.next(this._data);
}
get data() {
  return this._data$.asObservable();
}
```

then you can subscribe:

```
this.data.subscribe({
    next: (data) => {
        (...)
    }
})
```